# jqGrid ASP.NET WebForms cellurl doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I would like to edit my data in grid. I can edit it in table and see it but I don't go to the c# method. I tried with ajax but it doesn't work too...Serialization doesn't work too. What is wrong?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string LoadData()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Employees", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void UpdateGrid()
    {
        //code to actually do the update to the database
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Employees", cn);
    }
}
```

and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnEmployee").click(function () {
            var service = "Default.aspx/LoadData";
            var lastsel2;
            $.ajax({
                url: service,
                datatype: "json",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                method: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    result = result.d;
                    jQuery("#EmpTable").jqGrid({
                        datatype: "local",
                        colNames : ['Emp numb', 'First name', 'Second name', 'Salary'],
                        colModel: [
                            { name:"Emp_id", index: "Emp_id", width:80, editable: true},
                            { name: "First_name", index: "First_name", width: 80, editable: true},
                            { name: "Second_name", index: "Second_name", width: 80, editable: true},
                            { name: "Salary", index: "Salary", width: 80, editable: true}
                        ],
                        data: JSON.parse(result),
                        rowNum: 10,
                        loadonce: true,
                        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                        pager: '#EmpPager',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: 'asc',
                        gridview: true,
                        autowidth: true,
                        sortname: 'Emp_id', 
                        altRows: true,
                        hoverrows: true, 
                        onSelectRow: function (id) {
                            if (id && id !== lastsel2) {
                                jQuery('#EmpTable').restoreRow(lastsel2);
                                jQuery('#EmpTable').editRow(id, true);
                                lastsel2 = id;
                            }

                        },
                        caption: "Events",
                        cellurl: 'Default.aspx/UpdateGrid'
                    });
                    $("#EmpTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#EmpPager', { edit: true, add: true, del: false });
                    $("#EmpTable").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#EmpPager");

                    },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Oops!");
                }
            });
        });             
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code (both the server side and the client side) contains many errors. It's important to know, which version of jqGrid and from which fork you use (or can upgrade). Currently exist 3 main options: an old jqGrid in version <=4.7. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) - it's the fork which I develop. Commercial version [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Both free jqGrid and Guriddo jqGrid JS are mostly compatible to old jqGrid, but the set of new options become more and more different. The default value of `cellsubmit` is different too.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read about it.

Comment: and also  your public void UpdateGrid() method is making a SELECT query. not an UPDATE query.